# DC-HSPA Cellular Standard Indicator

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, nexus-4, cellular-radio

I have recently picked up a Nexus 4, on a carrier with a good DC-HSPA network (3 in the UK), and I want to check out the speed on that network. However, I don't know whether my phone has even picked up the DC-HSPA network. My speedtests have so far shown around 12Mbps down and 2Mbps up (one of which was in central London), so I can assume I'm only on HSPA+ at the moment.

I'd imagine DC would be roughly double that. The indicator next to the signal strength bar has only ever said H or 3G. Will it say something different when using DC? It's never even said H+, for that matter. Is it supposed to? Or is H just a blanket for all HSPA-related standards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-Speed_Downlink_Packet_Access) entry, this is **enhanced version of HSPA+**.

Now, reading from the [telephony source](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/jb-release/telephony/java/android/telephony/ServiceState.java#L72) in JellyBean, depending if its GSM, between the two lines numbered 72 and 107, there is nothing in there that indicates, the automatic detection of the usage of DC-HSPA and is probably being treated as HSPA+ for now in the interim, so its very highly likely that it will show up as a 'H' or '3G'.

And then again, that's dependent on the compile-time specifications used when the ROM was built, to elect to show '3G', 'H+' or even 'H' on the status bar.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the source, that was really helpful.

So, I guess there is no differentiation from HSPA+, and the H just refers to all of HSPA/HSPA+/DC-HSPA+.

Comment: @Luke Thanks for the accepting of the answer :) Yes, there's no differentiation with H, for now, maybe it will show in a later version of Android, who knows :)